# Not able to annotate a class with @XmlTransient annotation

Tags: java

Below is my code,

Where I am not able to annotate a class with `@XmlTransient` annotation,

netbeans IDE says annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration.

I have JDK 1.6 and Jaxb 1.5 running with netbeans.

Thanks for any help.

```
import com.duncansolutions.databus.external.util.xml.XMLDateAdapter;
import com.duncansolutions.databus.external.xml.parkmobile.PayByCell;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;


@XmlTransient
public class AddTime extends PayByCell implements Serializable{

private Integer transmissionId;
private Integer spaceNumber;


@XmlElement(name = "TransmissionID")
public Integer getTransmissionId() {
    return transmissionId;
}

public void setTransmissionId(Integer transmissionId) {
    this.transmissionId = transmissionId;
}

@XmlElement(name = "SpaceNumber")
public Integer getSpaceNumber() {
    return spaceNumber;
}

public void setSpaceNumber(Integer spaceNumber)
{
    this.spaceNumber = spaceNumber;
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XMLDateAdapter.class)
@XmlElement(name = "StartDateTime")
@Override
public Date getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XMLDateAdapter.class)
@XmlElement(name = "EndDateTime")
@Override
public Date getExpTime() {
    return expTime;
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value={FIELD,METHOD})
public @interface XmlTransient
```

As you can see annotation @XmlTransient only can be applied in FIELDs or METHODS. It is what the API said.
This annotation avoid that a specific member variable will be written in the representation of the object in XML.

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html), `@XmlTransient` is only applicable to a field or a method, not a class.  This is, of course, from Java EE 5; it seems that [in Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) and newer, you're allowed to do so.

If you want to use it, be sure that you're using a newer Java EE JAR.